# Gradle "Already seen doctype"

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I need to implement third party SDK in Android but constantly getting "Already seen doctype" error when I started project sync. I have placed the SDK in **app/libs** directory.

[image]

**Project Level (build.gradle)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://purelive.jfrog.io/artifactory/main"
            credentials {
                username ''
                password ''
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Level (build.gradle)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    namespace 'com.implementation.efr'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.implementation.efr"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            //shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation(name:'mfl-4.1.9', ext:'aar')
    implementation 'com.pure.live:sdk:6.3.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = "EFR"
include ':app'
```

This is my first time integrating and SDK. Please guide. TIA.